# File Upload with JAX-RS gives Bad arguments passed error

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I want to upload file with jax-rs. I start tomcat,then send request from postman but, I got exception the below. I ve tried to change resteasy dependencies but didn't solve my problem.

```
 Failed executing POST files/upload
    org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InternalServerErrorException: Bad arguments passed to public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
```

The below is my upload class.

```
@Path("/files")
public class FileUpload {
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        String fileLocation = "/home/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
        //saving file
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        String output = "File successfully uploaded to : " + fileLocation;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

The pom.xml file is the below. I'm confused that is the problem about dependencies.

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!--resteasy-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--rest-easy client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--unit test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.24.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

The below is my web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <!--Prefix for the endpoints-->
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.fileServer.app.HelloApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <!--Prefix for endpoint-->
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Don't mix Jersey with RESTEasy... period.

Comment: What do u mean? @PaulSamsotha

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between Jersey and RESTEasy?

Comment: Ok i miss typed that. I ve changed the name of question.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between Jersey and RESTEasy. The fact that you don’t understand what I mean by “don’t mix the two,” tells me you don’t know the difference. Please do some research on this. Once you figure it out, decide which one you want to use and use only that one. Both have support for Multipart, you just need to read the documentation.